# C -Wformat warning for integer promotion in printf

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I am using GCC 5.2.1 with an [ARM Cortex A9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A9), and compiling with -std=c11 and -Wformat-signedness.

**How do I avoid a -Wformat warning in this case?**

```
int main()
{
    enum
    {
        A = 0,
        B
    };
    char buff[100];
    snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", A);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a warning:

```
format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has
  type 'int' [-Werror=format=]
    snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", A);
                        ^
```

An explicit cast gives the same result:

```
format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has 
  type 'int' [-Werror=format=]
    snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", (uint16_t)A);
                        ^
```

Comment: If it's literally telling you you need an argument of type `unsigned int`, why are you casting to a different type than `unsigned int`?

Comment: Regarding why the cast didn't work, the warning is an effect of the "integer promotions" because `uint16_t` is defined by an integral type with a rank less than `int` on your system (presumably because `int` has a greater value range), so the converted `uint16_t` value gets automatically converted to `int` anyway. Cast to `unsigned int` like the compiler recommends.

Comment: @hvd Haha.. did the trick. Are they not merely typedefs? Terms like "int" are so vague when specifics like int32_t are available, hence why I preferred to use them. But there is no uintXX_t equivalent of "unsigned int" in this case.

Comment: The compiler tells you it expects `unsigned int`.  So instead, you cast to `uint16_t`, which is probably `unsigned short` on your system.  This then gets promoted to `int` when passed as an argument without type information in the function prototype.  Why not do *exactly* what the compiler suggests?

Comment: @JetskiS-type You're missing the point here.  If you use *any* typedef with a specific size built into it, then your code will not be portable because as soon as you run it on a machine with a larger integer size, you will again end up with the value becoming signed.

Comment: @TomKarzes I have become accustomed to using them without thinking, as I have come across int meaning different things on different platforms before, and intXX_t is a great way to be specific. This is the first time using the intXX_t form has not worked.

Comment: @TomKarzes Indeed, I have run into portability problems with printf format specifiers before on ARM 32-bit and x86_64 before. Printing uint32_t requires "%u" on one and "%lu" on the other (from memory.. could be wrong). But it would be nice if printf specifiers did match the stdint types.

Comment: @JetskiS-type The standard header `<inttypes.h>` provides macros for the `printf` and `scanf` family, such as `PRIx16` for printing a `uint16_t` value (though the value itself will still be promoted to `int` by the compiler if necessary), and `SCNxFAST16` for reading a `uint_fast16_t` value. For example, `snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04" PRIx16 "\n", (uint16_t)A);`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That's great, thanks (though unfortunately a bit ugly).

Comment: @JetskiS-type Agreed, which is why I stick to the primitive types when possible. Another reason I prefer the primitives is that the sized typedefs are intended for usage only when you need them (e.g. data structures), and the exact-sized `uint16_t` might not even exist! If you're working with a system that uses 36 bits natively, `uint18_t` might exist and be slower because any value smaller than 36 bits on that machine gets its unused bits masked automatically. `uint_least16_t` might be typedef'd to the same type as `uint18_t`, and `uint_fast16_t` could be `int` for speed purposes.

Comment: @etski S-type Still unclear: why `snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", (uint16_t)A);` instead of `snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", (unsigned)A);`?

Comment: @chux See my first reply which was to hvd: "Haha.. did the trick." Avoiding the vague "int" types is an automatic habit for me.

Comment: The vague `unsigned int` type can always hold `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I avoid a -Wformat warning in this case?

Cast the enumerated type to `unsigned` to match  `"%x"`.

```
// snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", A);
snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", (unsigned) A);
```

> `o,u,x,X` The `unsigned int` argument is converted to ... C11 §7.21.6.1 8

---

If code casts to something other than `unsigned`, [for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250200/c-wformat-warning-for-integer-promotion-in-printf?noredirect=1#comment91449215_52250200), use the specified matching print specifier. [@Chrono Kitsune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250200/c-wformat-warning-for-integer-promotion-in-printf?noredirect=1#comment91448697_52250200)

```
#include <inttypes.h> 

// snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04x\n", (uint16_t)A);
snprintf(buff, 100, "Value is 0x%04" PRIX16 "\n", (uint16_t)A);
```

---

Moral if the story: Use matching print specifiers with each argument.

Comment: The string should be: "Value is 0x%" PRIX16 "\n", however even that does not work: https://godbolt.org/z/gyhStF  warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

Comment: @JetskiS-type Please report 1) `puts(PRIX16);` (I'd expect `"hX"`) and 2) You may want a newer version of the compiler GCC 5.2.1 --> 7.3.0 as I am unable to replicate warning with  `'-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-Wformat=1'`.

Comment: @chux OP compiled with the `-Wformat-signedness` flag, which was added in one of the gcc 5.x releases (gcc 5.1 on Godbolt recognizes it, but not gcc 4.9.4). The flag's behavior is not currently enabled by any of the values that may be passed to `-Wformat` or by any of the `-pedantic`/`-Wpedantic`, `-Wextra`, or `-Wall` flags at any optimization level.

Comment: That said, `PRIX16` expands to `"X"` in that case, resulting in `"Value is 0x%" "X" "\n"`, both on my Linux system and on Godbolt. MSVC uses `"hX"` as one would perhaps more reasonably expect. Not sure why [glibc uses `"X"` up to `PRIX64`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/inttypes.h.html#_M/PRIX16).

Comment: @chux Don't be shy - use the Godbolt compiler explorer yourself! Also needs -Wall in addition to -Wformat-signedness.

Comment: @JetskiS-type To be fair to the implementation Godbolt's gcc is using, the warning is bogus if you're targeting most (all?) x86 and x86-64 implementations: the range from 0 to 65535 inclusive has the exact same bit representation whether interpreted as `int` or `unsigned int`. In other words, the implementation you see isn't incorrect per se; the warning merely suggests that you could make your code _more portable_ to implementations where `int` and `unsigned int` may have different bit representations (e.g. the values of padding bits may differ depending on signedness).